# efficient method to search based on strings in db2 using SQL query

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to search a column in db2 database if it contains words like either `insulin` or `asprin` or `advil`

Currently I wrote a query like this.

```
     select * from Table1 where 
     (
        Column1 like '%insulin%'
     or Column1 like '%asprin%'
     or Column1 like '%advil%'
     )
```

Is there anyway I can improve this query such that I dont have to type like three times ? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: you have to type as many times as the items you are searching for, unless a few search terms have something in common

Comment: @vkp, ah that is so inefficient dont you think especially when mySQL has some functions like rlike etc...

Comment: but you are using db2?

Comment: could you comment on what is stored in Column1? Depending on how the string looks like there could be more options to query.

Comment: what platform and version of DB2?

Comment: @data_henrik, Column1 is free text, all characters, numbers, and special characters.

Comment: @Charles, IBM db2 10.5 I believe

Comment: how long are the strings? The question is whether text search makes sense

Comment: Worse than you having to type it three times is 1) you need dynamic sql to add/remove search terms automatically and 2) this form of query won't use an index (slow on tables of any real size).  Not much help for this if it's user-supplied, though...